# test void simple method with spock

Tags: groovy, spock

I have the following method need to be tested:

```
class Person {

    String getFileName(String number) {
         return "file"+number
    }

    void updateSpec(String number) {
         new File(getFileName(number)).delete()
    }
}
```

I try to create the testcase like this:

```
def "update spec"() {
        given:
            Person person = new Person()

        when:
            person.updateSpec('1')

        then:
            1 * File.delete()
    }
```

it says:

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * File.delete()   (0 invocations)
```

what is the problem and how to fix it, thanks!

And is there a good way to test this method?

Comment: How does the Person class know what directory the file is in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what do you want to test. At first you have to use Mock or Spy to be able to test invocation count.

For example you can test if `getFileName()` method was called from `updateSpec()` method and if it was called with `'1'` argument like this:

```
def "update spec"() {
    given:
    Person person = Spy(Person)

    when:
    person.updateSpec('1')

    then:
    1 * person.getFileName('1')
}
```

If you really need to test whether the `File.delete()` was called, then it will be better to change `Person` class little bit, because you need `File` mock on which you can check the invocation count:

```
class Person {
    File getFile(String number) {
        return new File("file" + number)
    }

    void updateSpec(String number) {
        getFile(number).delete()
    }
}
```

And the test can be then:

```
def "File delete was called"() {
    given:
    File file = Mock(File)
    Person person = Spy(Person)
    person.getFile(_) >> file

    when:
    person.updateSpec('1')

    then:
    1 * file.delete()
}
```

Another option will be to inject some `FileService`, wich will encapsulate the `File.delete()` method, into the `Person` class and test invoication on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can only define interactions between the object under specification and its mocked dependencies. In your example, however, you are "specifying" an interaction with `File` class, not mock object. See Spock's [Interaction Based Testing](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.2/all_in_one.html#_interaction_based_testing). Technically, you can achieve/change your goal as suggested in @cgrim answer. Or you can use tools such as PowerMock (w/o Spock) to mock almost everything but REMEMBER, this kind of technique should only be taken as a last resort. Basically, if you adhere to best design practices then you will never need such tools. Unless you have to deal with some legacy code